# Match days, months and years on string

Tags: regex

I would like to match days, months and years in three different groups, so I would know that group[0] = years, group[1] = months, group[2] = days.

```
Ano == Year, Anos == Years<br>
Mes == Month, Meses == Months<br>
Dia == Day, Dias == Days<br><br>
```

**Input:**

```
   1 ano 12 meses 1 dia
    2 anos
    1 ano
    1 mes
    1 dia
    2 meses 1 dia
    1 mes 3 dias
    3 dias
```

Here's the pattern that I've tried:
`([0-9]+)ano*([0-9]+)mes*([0-9]+)dia`
**Output needed:**

```
    1 12 1 
    2 
    1 
    1 
    1 
    2 1 
    1 3 
    3
```

[Live Example:](http://www.regexr.com/39dnp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:(\d+) anos?)?(?:(?:^| )(\d+) mes(?:es)?)?(?:(?:^| )(\d+) dias?)?
```

The above pattern will work. You'd need to use the multiline flag (`m`) as well.

Here's an example: http://regex101.com/r/wA6xJ2/1

Comment: @TioTorres You need to enable the multiline and global flags.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?:(\d+)\s*ano\S*)?(?:\s*(\d+)\s*mes\S*)?(?:\s*(\d+)\s*dia\S*)?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/1)